# Is there "proprietary drivers" menu in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, additional-drivers

I have always used the "proprietary drivers" menu in Settings to install NVIDIA drivers, for example. Is this feature now gone? How is it assumed that novice users now install NVIDIA drivers? How do I even now which drivers I'm using?

Comment: You mean "Additional Drivers" tab in *Software & Updates*? Yes, it's there.

Comment: You now see it in the Settings of the update command, its not now in the system settings.

Comment: @oldfred Would you be willing to post an answer about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Software Updater]

Originally I found the Additional Drivers tab in software updater and Settings button. But if you search, you can directly find & go to Software & Updates. Both Software Updater and Software & Updates icons and screens shown.